# Ribbon Icon for new page form in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, icons, ribbon

I have created a new page to add additional details to the default task template in Outlook. The new page shows up in the ribbon, but with the icon as shown. How can I customize the icon so it matches the ones beside it? I tried to go to customize ribbon, but that doesn't even show up at all.

[image: Ribbon Icon]

Answer (score 0):

Could you find your own custom option in your Ribbon list? If so, you may could try to rename it and change its icon like below.
[image]

Comment: It has been a while, how is everything going?
If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.